# Detect Pixel-Blocks of an image

Tags: java, image-processing

I'm working on a code in Java, which should detect pixel-areas and create a list with the coordinates of the pixels which are connected to each other.
For each area I want to create a new list.

I wrote a method which should first detect the edges of the areas and then check if the pixels are connected to another. I hand over a black/white image and convert it into a 2D array of pixels. In each index I set the color of the equivalent pixel of the image. But it does not work.

**My question:** Is there any other solution to separate black areas of a black/white image to get the coordinates listed?

**Example:**

I have this image saved into an 2D Integer Array and if the color is Black the value at this index is "1" else if the color is white it's "-1".

I want to get 2 Lists (because there are 2 seperate areas)

> **First List:**  Coordinates [(1,1),(2,1),(0,2),(1,2),(2,2)]
>
> **Second List:** Coordinates [(6,2),(4,3),(5,3),(6,3),(7,3),(4,4),(5,4),(6,4)]

[image: Pixel Blocks with Coordinates]

**My Code:**

```
private static List<Group> detectGroups(BufferedImage image) {
    int[][] colorArray = imageToColorArray(image);
    List<Coordinate> edgeCoordinates = new ArrayList<Coordinate>();
    List<Group> pixelGroups = new ArrayList<Group>(); // empty now
    // Detect Edges
    for (int y = 1; y < colorArray[0].length - 1; y++) {
        for (int x = 1; x < colorArray.length - 1; x++) {
            if (colorArray[x][y] == black && colorArray[x - 1][y] == white
                    || colorArray[x][y] == black && colorArray[x + 1][y] == white
                    || colorArray[x][y] == black && colorArray[x][y - 1] == white
                    || colorArray[x][y] == black && colorArray[x][y + 1] == white) {
                colorArray[x][y] = edge;
                edgeCoordinates.add(new Coordinate(x, y));
            }
        }
    }
    // Detect Groups
    for (int i = 0; i < edgeCoordinates.size(); i++) {
        Coordinate index = edgeCoordinates.get(i);
        int x = index.getX();
        int y = index.getY();

        Coordinate c = new Coordinate(x, y);
        Coordinate topLeftFromPixel = new Coordinate(x - 1, y - 1);
        Coordinate topMiddleFromPixel = new Coordinate(x, y - 1);
        Coordinate topRightFromPixel = new Coordinate(x + 1, y - 1);
        Coordinate middleLeftFromPixel = new Coordinate(x - 1, y);
        Coordinate middleRightFromPixel = new Coordinate(x + 1, y);
        Coordinate bottomLeftFromPixel = new Coordinate(x - 1, y + 1);
        Coordinate bottomMiddleFromPixel = new Coordinate(x, y + 1);
        Coordinate bottomRightFromPixel = new Coordinate(x + 1, y + 1);

        if (pixelGroups.isEmpty()) {
            Group group = new Group();
            group.addCoordinate(c);
            pixelGroups.add(group);
        } else {
            /*
             * Überprüfe ob die Pixel sich berühren und ermittle Pixelgruppen und erstelle
             * falls nötig eine neue Gruppe
             */

            for (int j = 0; j < pixelGroups.size(); j++) {
                List<Coordinate> coordinates = pixelGroups.get(j).getCoordinates();

                for (int l = 0; l < coordinates.size(); l++) {
                    Coordinate k = coordinates.get(l);
                    if (k.equals(topLeftFromPixel) || k.equals(topMiddleFromPixel) || k.equals(topRightFromPixel)
                            || k.equals(middleLeftFromPixel) || k.equals(middleRightFromPixel)
                            || k.equals(bottomLeftFromPixel) || k.equals(bottomMiddleFromPixel)
                            || k.equals(bottomRightFromPixel)) {
                        pixelGroups.get(j).addCoordinate(c);
                    } else {
                        Group newGroup = new Group();
                        newGroup.addCoordinate(c);
                         pixelGroups.add(0, newGroup);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return pixelGroups;
}
```

Comment: is the raster size known? can it change? and what is a pixel area? are those large black squares supposed to represent pixels? or is that an example image you want to process, not just a zoomed view of pixels?

Comment: @Piglet The image I showed above represents a zoomed image. Each black box is a pixel and inside of the box I wrote the coordinates to understand this problem better.

A pixel area is a combination of black pixels.

Comment: google blob detection, connected component, region growing, it's a very common problem in image processing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming that image of yours is supposed to view a magnified image with single pixels.

Finding connected groups of pixels is a very common problem in image-processing. There are many different methods.

Those connected regions are often called BLOBS (binary large objects) or connected components, regions, ...

You will find algorithms to do that under names like blob detector, connected component analysis,...

I suggest you read [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected-component_labeling) as a starting point.